# connect BLE device through service UUID on andorid

Tags: android

I am doing below code block

```
var mSocket: BluetoothSocket
try {
    mSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(DeviceProfile.UUID_SERVICE)
    if (!mSocket.isConnected) {
        mSocket.connect()
    }
} catch (e1: IOException) {
    e1.printStackTrace()
}
```

All time I am getting below error
error: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Anyone has any solution? OR How do I coonect BLE device through service UUID?

I want to connect Bluetooth device through GATT over Bluetooth classic.

Comment: _" want to connect Bluetooth device through GATT over Bluetooth classic._ AFAIK this is not possible. What do you actually want to _do_ with the BLE device? I.e. why can't you discover the device's services and characteristics, and then read/write data from/to those characteristics?

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. You say that you want to connect to a BLE device over Bluetooth Classic. Bluetooth Classic and BLE are two different things. GATT is however supported on both transports. Instead of trying to connect to rfcomm socket, use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#connectGatt(android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback,%20int) and set transport to BR/EDR.

Comment: When I am using GATT to connect to Blueth LE device, it it is success but not getting actual service UUID. So I want to connect the device through service UUID then I can get the characteristic also within the service UUID.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import java.util.UUID

class BluetoothLEManager(private val context: Context) {

    private lateinit var bluetoothGatt: BluetoothGatt
    private lateinit var serviceUUID: UUID // Specify your service UUID here

    fun connectToDevice(device: BluetoothDevice, serviceUUID: UUID) {
        this.serviceUUID = serviceUUID
        bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback)
    }

    private val gattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {
        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.d("BluetoothLEManager", "Connected to GATT server.")
                gatt?.discoverServices()
            } else if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Log.d("BluetoothLEManager", "Disconnected from GATT server.")
            }
        }

        override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.d("BluetoothLEManager", "Services discovered successfully.")
                val services: List<BluetoothGattService> = gatt?.services ?: return
                for (service in services) {
                    if (service.uuid == serviceUUID) {
                        val characteristics: List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> = service.characteristics
                        for (characteristic in characteristics) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.w("BluetoothLEManager", "onServicesDiscovered received: $status")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to connect the Bluetooth LE device through service UUID. Using this GATT, I am not getting specific service UUID from the device.

Comment: I modified my code to a new one and edited the prior one for this query because I'm not receiving the device's particular service UUID.